# Hardening further mysql with sqlmap suggestion

Tags: mysql, php

I just ran this tool called sqlmap. It gave me this few list as below.

```
sqlmap identified the following injection points with a total of 0 HTTP(s) requests:
---
Parameter: ID (GET)
    Type: boolean-based blind
    Title: AND boolean-based blind - WHERE or HAVING clause
    Payload: ta=asaa&ID=74 AND 3387=3387&na=0&bc=C

    Type: UNION query
    Title: MySQL UNION query (NULL) - 6 columns
    Payload: ta=asaa&ID=74 UNION ALL SELECT NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,CONCAT(0x71766a7171,0x78587565526f656b4e4b,0x716a707871)#&na=0&bc=C

    Type: AND/OR time-based blind
    Title: MySQL > 5.0.11 AND time-based blind
    Payload: ta=asaa&ID=74=74 AND SLEEP(5)&na=0&bc
```

I tested on the union query doest not give any result. But booleand-based blind do give the result and time based-based blind kind of stop my application? What can I do to improvise?

Comment: Can you share the queries that the results are referring to? What language is your application written in? Are you using parameterized / stored procedures?

Comment: I am using php as the language.My query is infact very simple I have read about prepared statement but I find it a bit time consuming to move now. Here is my query SELECT eStatus,gName,gPreference FROM eventL WHERE ID=".$ID." Order By tID Asc as for now what can I improvise?

Comment: Using prepared statements is how you protect against injection - read up on the [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) covering it.

Comment: Is it ok for me to use mysql escape string for time being cause of time constrain? The prepared statement will need to recode a lot of stuff?

Comment: That depends on your risk tolerance. As [shown on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string), yes, it's possible to still use injection with escape strings.

Comment: So what you advice to go with prepared statement or stored procedures? Which will be easier to move from my existing type of queries ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't much you can do to "improvise", you need to fix the issue at hand: you're vulnerable to SQL injections.

The most straightforward solution to this is to implement **parameterized queries** in your code. This will involve changing all the queries manually, but will protect you.

You can read up on it from the article [What's the Right Way to Prevent SQL Injection in PHP](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/brian_swan/whats-the-right-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php-scripts), but here's an excerpt from the article:

> For example, consider the following login script:
>
> `$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserTbl WHERE Username = '$username' and Password = '$password'";`
>
> Let’s use the same script, but I’ll define the SQL query with parameter placeholders:
>
> `$sql = "SELECT * FROM UserTbl WHERE Username = ? and Password = ?";`
>
> Now, I’ll define an array that holds the parameter values:
>
> `$params = array($_POST['Username’], $_POST['Password’]);`
>
> When I execute the query, I pass the $params array as an argument:
>
> `$stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $sql, $params);`

Comment: Say I am sending data via get and also post do I need to sanitize first for parameterized queries . The sample you gave is not for mysql right? Another thing what I am confused is paramterised queries and pdo? Which one to be used?